# How do I solve this equation: $\sqrt[x]{x+2}+\sqrt[x]{x-3}=2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, i tried like this:
$$(x+2)^{\frac{1}{x}}+(x-3)^{\frac{1}{x}}=2 \implies \frac{1}{x}\ln(x+2)+\frac{1}{x}\ln(x-3)=\ln{2} \implies \frac{1}{x}(\ln(x+2)+\ln(x-3))=\ln{2} \implies$$ $$\implies \ln(x+2)+\ln(x-3)=x\cdot \ln{2} \implies \ln(x^2-x-6)=\ln{2^x} \implies x^2-x-6=2^x \implies x\approx -2.04791$$

But this is obviously not true, please tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\ln(A+B)\neq\ln A +\ln B$ in general.

Comment: Where is the equation from ?

Comment: "How do I solve this equation?"  You can solve it numerically.

Comment: You want a real solution?

Comment: @Paul Frost Yeah, or as in wolfram it is written "numerical".

Comment: @Yves Daoust found on the internet.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash sorry, I don't know how to use it correctly)

Comment: Note that your expression is only defined for $x > 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\sqrt[x]{x+2}+\sqrt[x]{x-3}-2$$ which, in the real domain, is only defined if $x \geq 3$.

We have $$f(3)=\sqrt[3]{5}-2=-0.290024 <0\qquad \text{and}\qquad f(4)=\sqrt[4]{6}-1=0.565085>0$$

Using Taylor expansion around $x=3$, we have
$$f(x)=\left(\sqrt[3]{5}-2\right)+\sqrt[3]{x-3}+(x-3) \left(\frac{1}{3\
   5^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{9} \sqrt[3]{5} \log (5)\right)+O\left((x-3)^{4/3}\right)$$ Being lazy, using the first and second terms
$$\left(\sqrt[3]{5}-2\right)+\sqrt[3]{x-3}=0 \implies x_0=6 \left(1-2\times 5^{1/3}+5^{2/3}\right)=3.02440$$ For this value $f(x_0)=-0.00173125$ which means that we are now quite close to the solution.

Being less lazy, introducing the next termand letting $x=y^3+3$, we face the ugly depressed cubic equation
$$\frac{ (3-5 \log (5))}{9\ 5^{2/3}}y^3+y+\left(\sqrt[3]{5}-2\right)=0$$ which has three real roots; so, it can be solved using the trigonometric method. The solution is so ugly that I just produce its numerical value
$$y=0.2949450186\implies x_1=3.02565802341\implies f(x_1)=0.00311101$$

which is not better but, at least, the solution has been bracketed.

Now, polish the root using Newton method starting at $x_0$; the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 3.024395069 \\
 1 & 3.024838919 \\
 2 & 3.024841659
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the “open” solution, not closed, but here is my solution using this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/szefiydyss):

$$(x+2)^\frac 1x=2-(x-3)^\frac 1x\implies x= (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2 =x$$

Let $a_1(x)=  (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2,a_{n+1}(x)=a_n(a_n(x))$

Therefore:
$$x=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n(x),x≈  (2-({ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-3)^\frac 1{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2})^{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-2,$$

or

$$   (2-({ (2-({  (2-({ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-3)^\frac 1{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2})^{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-2}-3)^\frac 1{  (2-({ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-3)^\frac 1{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2})^{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-2})^{  (2-({ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-3)^\frac 1{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2})^{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-2}-2}-3)^\frac 1{ (2-({  (2-({ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-3)^\frac 1{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2})^{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-2}-3)^\frac 1{  (2-({ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-3)^\frac 1{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2})^{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-2})^{  (2-({ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-3)^\frac 1{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2})^{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-2}-2})^{ (2-({  (2-({ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-3)^\frac 1{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2})^{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-2}-3)^\frac 1{  (2-({ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-3)^\frac 1{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2})^{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-2})^{  (2-({ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-3)^\frac 1{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2})^{ (2-(x-3)^\frac 1x)^x-2}-2}-2}-2$$
$$\mathrm{\ or\ }...$$

Please correct me and give me feedback! Please see the graphical proof of this to see this converges rapidly.

I will work on this more with the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

$$\left((x+2)^\frac 1x+(x-3)^\frac 1x=2\right)^x\implies 2^x=\sum_{k=0}^x\binom xk (x+2)^{x-k}(x-3)^k= \sum_{k=0}^x\binom xk (x-3)^{x-k}(x+2)^k $$

You can use the Binomial Theorem on the binomials here, but I doubt this would be of any help. I may have made a mistake with the binomial expression as the powers seem to cancel out.

Here is another similar solution [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3kjwougbmq). Notice the horizontal line like function.

Comment: This is an old answer